# Change unicode hardwrited in csv to corresponding character

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, encoding

I have a csv with 1 column having hard writed unicode character :

```
["Investir dans un parc d'activit\u00e9s"]
["S\u00e9curiser, restaurer et g\u00e9rer 1 372 ha de milieux naturels impact\u00e9s par la construction de l'autoroute"]
["Am\u00e9liorer la consommation \u00e9nerg\u00e9tique de b\u00e2timents publics"]
["Favoriser la recherche, am\u00e9liorer la qualit\u00e9 des traitements et assurer un \u00e9gal acc\u00e8s des soins \u00e0 tous les patients de Franche-Comt\u00e9."]
```

I'm trying to fix/replace them with the corresponding char, but I can't seems to make it, I tried with

```
df['Objectif(s)'] = df['Objectif(s)'].replace('\u00e9', 'é')
```

but the column don't change
Seing that the code below work, I tried to loop over the row to fix it with no success

```
s = "d'activit\u00e9s"
print(s)   # d'activités
print(s.replace('\u00e9', 'é' ))   # d'activités

for case in df['Objectif(s)']:
    s = str(case)
    df['Objectif(s)'][case] = s   # ["Investir dans un parc d'activit\u00e9s"]
```

Comment: could it be that "\u00e9" is actually written in the file (without encoding), indicating that the source of the data has written this as characters into a text file ? --> please post binary input file to check the actual binary content to figure out the encoding of such.

Comment: @EdwinvanMierlo Yes that what I mean by "hardwrited" in , its not a problem of encoding, I want to replace those unicode with the real char

Comment: please see my answer

Comment: @EdwinvanMierlo thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if this `'\u00e9'` is actually written into the file as `\` `u` `0` `0` `e` `9` as normal characters by the source of the data, you need to do a string replace.

the trick here is that you need to escape the `\` character in the replace function first parameter

```
s.replace('\\u00e9', 'é' )
```

or use a "raw string literal" by prefixing `r`

```
s.replace(r'\u00e9', 'é' )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
df['Objectif(s)'] = df['Objectif(s)'].replace('\u00e9', 'é')
```

to

```
df['Objectif(s)'] = df['Objectif(s)'].str.replace('\u00e9', 'é')
```